# How to convert a JsonNode instance to an actual pojo

Tags: java, jackson

At a certain point in my code, I have parse a JSON document, represented as a string, to a `JsonNode`, because I don't know yet the actual target pojo class type.

Now, some time later, I know the `Class` instance of the pojo and I want to convert this `JsonNode` to an actual pojo of that class (which is annotated with the proper `@JsonProperty` annotations). Can this be done? If so, how?

I am working with Jackson 2.10.x.

Comment: If this involves serializing the `JsonNode` back to a string and then deserializing it to the required pojo afterwards, then maybe I should not parse the JSON document as a `JsonNode` initially, but instead pass it through as a string until I know the pojo type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can use two methods:

- [treeToValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#treeToValue-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode-java.lang.Class-)
- [convertValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-)

See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class JsonNodeConvertApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonFile);

        System.out.println(mapper.treeToValue(node, Message.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.convertValue(node, Message.class));
    }
}

class Message {
    private int id;
    private String body;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code for `JSON` payload like below:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "body": "message body"
}
```

prints:

```
Message[id=1, body='message body']
Message[id=1, body='message body']
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between those two methods?

Comment: @Hazzo, `JavaDoc` for `treeToValue` method says: "Convenience conversion method that will bind data given JSON tree contains into specific value (usually bean) type. Functionally equivalent to: `objectMapper.convertValue(n, valueClass);`" So, you should be able to use both but prefer to use `treeToValue` if you can.